# C# PhantomJS Xpath Issues

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, phantomjs

code:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace Scrape
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.regmovies.com/theatres/theatre-folder/edwards-west-oaks-mall-stadium-14-rpx-9364");
            var nodes = driver.FindElementsByXPath(".//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/h3/a");
            foreach(var node in nodes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(node.Text);

            }
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

the xpath is valid because it returns something on firebug 
however it doesn't show any text.

whats going on?

however setting the xpath to

```
var nodes = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//a");
```

yields the movie names but not the specific xpath. what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Try *[waiting](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git-history/selenium-2.28.0/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) for the results to appear* before getting the show links:

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible((By.CssSelector("div.results"))));
```

Comment: How many languages do you know alecxe? hahha

you've helped me before in python too!. hold on I'll try it out

Comment: @Zion it's just that the selenium API is quite similar in different languages. I also don't particularly like the XPath you are using to locate the links, but this should not be relevant to the problem. Let's approach it step by step though and see if the wait helps. Thanks.

Comment: It's the raw xpath from firebug. 

it doesn't work..

have you tried it?

but using this 
`var nodes = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//a")` works it gets the movie names but some other extra stuff.

and there is no need for a wait for that one. it's extremely odd

Comment: @Zion okay, let's try this one: `//div[@class="title"]/h3/a`.

Comment: that one doesn't work however.
`//div[@class="title"]//a` does it's either im missing something with `c#'s` xpath or what. because Im almost 100% certain the `xpath` you gave me would work in python

Comment: @Zion got it, let's make a following test - switch to firefox or chrome driver and see if you can reproduce the problem there. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98519/discussion-between-alecxe-and-zion).